# MODX - File TV in cojnunction with MiniShop2 module

Tags: modx, television

I have some problems with "File" TV in conjunction with Minishop2 module . Unfortunately this tv input field extends outside of a browsers viewport, and my client is not able to make changes (attach files).

Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/q308V.jpg

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug of MODX 2.2.7, that already fixed.

http://tracker.modx.com/issues/9825